# Getting an error running the google script api quickstart for android

Tags: android, google-apps-script

I have the script and drive apis enabled and also have checked the credentials and all seems ok. Both the script and android clients are in the same project and The scriptId used in the project comes from the published script.  This is a generic error. The project does not exist. Any suggestions? I saw one post that indicated a typo in the app name might cause this, but not much else.

following error occurred:
403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Google Apps Script Execution API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/script/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Google Apps Script Execution API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/script/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}

Comment: Given that you enabled the correct APIs, is the package name in the quickstart sample the one you indicated in your Google Dev Console? Also did you generate your SHA1 certificate ?

Comment: yes I used my package name in the sha1 certificate.  I was also unsure what the Application name should be 
        public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.script.Script.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, setHttpTimeout(credential))
                    .setApplicationName("Android Quickedit")
                    .build();
        }

Answer (score 1):

ok, I figured it out.

1.)  there are two credentials in the project the script is tied to, that project is a resource for the script. (my credentials were ok)

2.) Once I built a signed apk and set gradle up to do that, then my app was no longer 'unregistered' then things started to work as expected.

I built my keystore, set up the api console right including credentials and did not generate a signed apk on the build.

one of the things that generates this is an unregistered client